# Getting statuses after gdb finishes

Tags: c, gdb

When GDB finishes, I get the following output:

```
─── Output/messages ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
[Inferior 1 (process 18473) exited with code 05]
```

- Is there a way to capture the exit code in the prompt, `5`, after gdb has finished?
- Does `18473` refer to the thread ID, the (unix) process ID, or something else?
- Finally, why it is called an "inferior" process?

Comment: It's possible that Richard Stallman, having been a developer on [ITS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incompatible_Timesharing_System), where the top-level process in a user session was a debugger and the process tree was described in terms of superior and inferior processes, carried the terminology over when he wrote gdb..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to capture the exit code in the prompt, 5, after gdb has finished?

In GDB, you could use `$_exitcode` [convenience variable](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Vars.html).

> Does 18473 refer to the thread ID, the (unix) process ID, or something else?

The UNIX process ID.

> Finally, why it is called an "inferior" process?

That's just what GDB developers call it. It the same as "the process GDB is debugging" (as opposed to the GDB process itself), and is much shorter. It's also "inferior" to GDB in the sense that GDB is controlling it (making it stop, single-step, or run as GDB desires).